# TF 1.3 build hangs with CUDA-9 on ppc64le

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build TF 1.3 with CUDA-9 on Ubuntu ppc64le. With all the required patches for CUDA-9 support (eigen, nccl, and even [TF's PR] (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/12502), I'm able to build most of TF code, however, it gets stucked at compilation of tensorflow/core/kernels/fft_ops.cc.
I checked TF1.3 with CUDA-8 and it builds without any issues on ppc64le. Has anybody experienced this kind of problem? I've tried bazel 0.4.5 as well as 0.5.3 and with both the versions, the problem persists. Even unpatching TF's PR for CUDA-9 support has no effect on the build problem.

Comment: I found that calls to all FFT kernel registrations for CPU in fft_ops.cc file are causing the hang but not sure how and why. Commenting out that code also let TF to compile successfully. Any pointers on this would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I found the cause for this hang. This was due to a local change in Eigen that has been working for us for older TF (< 1.3) + CUDA-8 but not with new TF (>1.3) and CUDA-9 with their respective Eigens. Hence closing this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause for this hang. This was due to a local change in Eigen that has been working for us for older TF (< 1.3) + CUDA-8 but not with new TF (>1.3) and CUDA-9 with their respective Eigens. On Ubuntu, the problem was raised in the form of hang with no clue whereas RHEL was kind enough to throw the exact error.
Thanks,
Nishidha